When Using ODBC Query in excel how do you use contains with the where?
When i use an ODBC query (Shown below) in excel it will return exact matches
SELECT  "SURNAME","FORENAME"
FROM DATABASEname
WHERE ("SURNAME"='PARKINSON' and "FORENAME"='CRAIG')

If the forename is Craig Bruce it will not show any results.
My initial thouights were:
SELECT  "SURNAME","FORENAME"
FROM DATABASE
WHERE CONTAINS("SURNAME"='PARKINSON' and "FORENAME"='CRAIG')

Also tried
SELECT  "SURNAME","FORENAME"
FROM DATABASE
WHERE ("SURNAME"='PARKINSON') and ("FORENAME" like %CRAIG%) 

but no matter how i alter the query the "contains" for the Forename does not bring any results just lots of Datasource errors

Try skipping the double quotes SELECT  SURNAME,FORENAME
FROM DATABASE
WHERE SURNAME='PARKINSON' and FORENAME='CRAIG'

Also when using like is should have single quotes '%CRAIG%'

What Datasource errors do you get?

SELECT SURNAME,FORENAME FROM DATABASE WHERE FORENAME like '%CRAIG%'

When trying to find if a field contains a string you can also use WHERE 0 < CHARINDEX('CRAIG',FORENAME)
